# Как передать сигнал по bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Допустим у меня есть два приложения. При нажатии на кнопку в первом устройстве, оно должно передать команду другому, чтобы другое... допустим, показало текст.

**Вопрос:** как отправлять сигналы по bluetooth на второе устройство так, чтобы, при отправке определенной команды с первого устройства, второе "словило" эту команду и обработало в слушателе?

P.S. Под командой я подразумеваю любое сообщение, будь то строка или цифра, или еще что-то, что можно передать и распознать. У обоих устройств будет включен bluetooth, если требуется — будет и ручная настройка.

Comment: разделите ваш вопрос на три отдельных, и задайте их отдельно.

Comment: @metalurgus, я обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите пример BluetoothChat из Android SDK.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?